# How can i create 2 for loops to replace values in Numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop

How can i use two for loops to replace the values in x with the row number, starting at 1, so it should be [[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2] … [5,5,5,5,5]]

x=np.ones((5,5))
print(x)

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use `for` loops with numpy? It's an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `for` loops in numpy, use broadcasting:

```
x=np.ones((5,5))

x[:] = np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None]+1
```

Updated `x`:

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5.]])
```

Alternatives:

```
x[:] = np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis]+1
```

Or:

```
x[:] = np.arange(x.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)+1
```

Comment: one nit -- use `np.newaxis` instead of `None` so it makes it a bit clearer what's happening

Comment: @jkr you're probably right, although `np.newaxis` just points to `None` ;)